# Calculated column syntax when using a group by function Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to include a column calculated as a % of OTYPE.
IE
Order type | Status | volume of orders at each status | % of all orders at this status

```
SELECT 
T.OTYPE,
STATUS_CD,
COUNT(STATUS_CD) AS STATVOL,
(STATVOL / COUNT(ROW_ID)) * 100

FROM Database.S_ORDER O

LEFT JOIN /* Finding definitions for status codes & attaching */
(
SELECT 
ROW_ID AS TYPEJOIN,
"NAME" AS OTYPE
FROM database.S_ORDER_TYPE
) T

ON T.TYPEJOIN = ORDER_TYPE_ID


GROUP BY (T.OTYPE, STATUS_CD)
/*Excludes pending and pending online orders */
WHERE  CAST(CREATED AS DATE) =  '2018/09/21'  AND  STATUS_CD <> 'Pending' 
AND STATUS_CD <> 'Pending-Online'
ORDER BY T.OTYPE, STATUS_CD DESC

OTYPE   STATUS_CD                    STATVOL TOTALPERC
Add New Service Provisioning         2,740   100
Add New Service In-transit           13      100
Add New Service Error - Provisioning 568     100
Add New Service Error - Integration  1       100
Add New Service Complete             14,387  100
```

Current output just puts 100 at every line, need it to be a % of total orders

Could anyone help out a Teradata & SQL student?
The complication making this difficult is my understanding of the group by and count syntax is tenuous. It took some fiddling to get it displayed as I have it, I'm not sure how to introduce a calculated column within this combo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only thing I *think* is wrong is the parenthesis around the group by columns. You don't need them. Apart from that, what other calculated columns do you want? This should all work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply tom!

Comment: Sadly mouse without borders failed me and the post wasn't my latest version of the query.
You were right about the parentheses, but this is my existing working code, so perhaps I should have entered the formula I can't find a place for.

Ideally I'm trying to add a column which shows what % of total orders the figures in column 3 are. My terminology might be off here, but I have two aggregations here, first being on the OrderType(otype) and the next being by status (Status_CD). When i try and add a derived column, I run into issues with it not being grouped.

Comment: (STATVOL / COUNT(ROW_ID)) * 100  --
ROW_ID being the previously grouped uniques for each row.

Comment: Ok, that's easy. Need a second nested query. I'll add an answer.

Comment: You really need to provide **sample data** and **expected results** for speedy/accurate answers

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of places the total could be done, but this is the way I would do it. I also cleaned up your other sub query which was not required, and changed the date to a non-ambiguous format (change it back if it cases an issue in Teradata)

```
SELECT 
    T."NAME" as OTYPE,
    STATUS_CD,
    COUNT(STATUS_CD) AS STATVOL,
    COUNT(STATUS_CD)*100/TotalVol as Pct
FROM database.S_ORDER O
LEFT JOIN EDWPRDR_VW40_SBLCPY.S_ORDER_TYPE T on T.ROW_ID = ORDER_TYPE_ID
cross join (select count(*) as TotalVol from database.S_ORDER) Tot
GROUP BY T."NAME", STATUS_CD, TotalVol
WHERE  CAST(CREATED AS DATE) =  '2018-09-21'  AND  STATUS_CD <> 'Pending' AND STATUS_CD <> 'Pending-Online'
ORDER BY T."NAME", STATUS_CD DESC
```

Comment: Hey thanks Tom, I'm a learner so it might take me a bit to get back to confirm the outcome but really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. A `where clause` comes before a `group by` clause, so the query
   shown in the question isn't valid.
2. **Always** prefix **every** column reference with the relevant table alias, below I have assumed that where you did not use the alias that it belongs to the orders table.
3. You probably do not need a subquery for this left join. While there are times when a subquery is needed or good for performance, this does not appear to be the case here.
4. Most modern SQL compliant databases provide "window functions", and Teradata does do this. They are extremely useful, and here when you combine `count()` with an `over clause` you can get the total of all rows without needing another subquery or join.
5. Because there is neither **sample data** nor **expected result** provided with the question I do not actually know which numbers you really need for your percentage calculation. Instead I have opted to show you different ways to count so that you can choose the right ones. I suspect you are getting 100 for each row because the count(status_cd) is equal to the count(row_id). You need to count status_cd differently to how you count row_id. *nb: The `count()` function increases by 1 for **every non-null value***
6. I changed the way your date filter is applied. It is not efficient to change data on every row to suit constants in a where clause. Leave the data untouched and alter the way you apply the filter to suit the data, this is almost always more efficient (search `sargable`)

---

```
SELECT
    t.OTYPE
  , o.STATUS_CD
  , COUNT(o.STATUS_CD)          count_status
  , COUNT(t.ROW_ID              count_row_id
  , count(t.row_id) over()      count_row_id_over
FROM dbo.S_ORDER o
    LEFT JOIN dbo.S_ORDER_TYPE t ON t.TYPEJOIN = o.ORDER_TYPE_ID
    /*Excludes pending and pending online orders */
WHERE o.CREATED >= '2018-09-21' AND o.CREATED <  '2018-09-22'
    AND o.STATUS_CD <> 'Pending'
    AND o.STATUS_CD <> 'Pending-Online'
GROUP BY
    t.OTYPE
  , o.STATUS_CD
ORDER BY
    t.OTYPE
  , o.STATUS_CD DESC
```

Comment: Of course, `where` comes before `group by`, but the parser accepts a wrong order as long as the first keyword is `select`. Teradata is older than Standard SQL, the previous QUEL-based syntax was more relaxed and there are still some leftovers :-)

Comment: And the `count(t.row_id) over()` will not work, because after aggregation there's no more `row_id`. Should be `sum(count(t.row_id)) over()` instead

Comment: Thank you to the both of you (dnoeth once again).  Both the theory and practical applications are valuable. Understanding why i can get away with something that isn't best-practice, but still understanding best-practice is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

As @TomC already noted, there's no need for the join to a Derived Table. The simplest way to get the percentage is based on a *Group Sum*. I also changed the date to an Standard SQL *Date Literal* and moved the `where` before `group by`.

```
SELECT 
   t."NAME",
   o.STATUS_CD,
   Count(o.STATUS_CD) AS STATVOL,
-- rule of thumb: multiply first then divide, otherwise you will get unexpected results
-- (Teradata rounds after each calculation)
   100.00 * STATVOL / Sum(STATVOL) Over ()

FROM database.S_ORDER AS O
 /* Finding definitions for status codes & attaching */
LEFT JOIN database.S_ORDER_TYPE AS t
  ON t.ROW_ID = o.ORDER_TYPE_ID

/*Excludes pending and pending online orders */
 -- if o.CREATED is a Timestamp there's no need to apply the CAST
WHERE Cast(o.CREATED AS DATE) =  DATE '2018-09-21'
  AND o.STATUS_CD NOT IN ('Pending', 'Pending-Online')

GROUP BY (T.OTYPE, o.STATUS_CD)

ORDER BY T.OTYPE, o.STATUS_CD DESC
```

Btw, you probably don't need an *Outer Join*, *Inner* should return the same result.

Comment: I was wondering that, with the outer/inner join. Thank you for providing that clarity. This thread is teaching me a great deal, I appreciate the depth of your answers.

Comment: Also, Created is a Date/time field. I'm under the impression that casting was more efficient here, or I would need to set a range of time in addition to the simple date. You guys might have tricks I'm unaware of.

Comment: @JimAnderson: If `Created` is a timestamp you can simply write `WHERE o.CREATED =  DATE '2018-09-21'`, when a timestamp is compared to a date there's an automatic typecast from timestamp to date. It might be more efficient to keep the datatype: `WHERE o.CREATED >= TIMESTAMP '2018-09-21 00:00:00' and o.CREATED < TIMESTAMP '2018-09-22 00:00:00`